# Проектирование таблиц базы, хранение данных

Tags: sql, база-данных, firebird

У меня пользователь создает объект исследования, образец какого-либо вещества - вода, золотосодержащая руда и т.д.
Пользователь вводит название исследуемого объекта и добавляет его свойства.
Свойствами (property) могут быть дата поступления образца, масса, участок отбора и др. То есть пользователь добавляет всю информацию,
которую он хотел бы хранить об этом образце.

Я думаю что нужно сделать таблицы:

- objects [id name description]
- samples [id objects_id number]
- properties [id name description]
- samples_properties [samples_id properties_id value]

В objects добавляется новый исследуемый образец, в samples хранятся все исследуемые образцы, относящиеся к конкретному типу. Меня смущает samples_properties
ведь если у нас образцов одного типа например миллион, и, если у этого типа образцов по 20 свойств, то samples_properties будет содержать минимум 20 млн строк.
И еще, мне не понятно нормально ли хранить значение свойства (value) в строке, будь то свойство цифра или дата.

Answer (score 1):

Что Вы хотите - это Entity-attribute-value model:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model

Чтобы строки хранить как строки, числа как числа, даты как даты и т.д., тогда для каждого типа создаётся отдельная таблица. Так что либо всё в стоках, либо по таблице на каждый тип:
samples_text_properties[samples_id properties_id value]
samples_data_properties[samples_id properties_id value]
и т.д. и т.п.

Чтобы не бояться 20 мильёнов строк, обратите внимание на раздел про JSON и XML.
Бросайте firebird, переходите на Postgres. Хотя в firebird тоже можно сохранить и json и xml, но они там будут просто текстом. В Postgres-е же для этого имеются специальные типы данных, которые имеют массу преимуществ против обычного текста.
При этом все ваши properties все вместе будут храниться в виде строк в одном json или xml документе.
В Postgres, если что, есть возможность делать запросы по полям в json и xml.

Comment: По Postgres какой вы используете клиент для работы с этой СУБД? Просто интересно.

Comment: Клиента сам пишу:) Или Вы имеете в виду админку? pgAdmin3. Для новых версий постгреса выпустили pgAdmin4, очень ужасно тормозит и не функционален. Надо искать специальный выпуск pgAdmin3 с поддержкой новых версий постгреса

Comment: На офф сайте такого разве нет нет? Я потому и взял firebird отказавшись от pgAdmin4.

Comment: На официальном нет. Если под виндой сидите, то есть BigData или BigDb точно не помню. У них дистрибутив постгреса с адаптированным pgAdmin3. Выйти по ссылкам можно через оффсайт постгреса

Comment: Я думаю что пока "посижу" на firebird, пока те не сделают нормальный клиент.:)

Comment: Ещё находил отдельный допиленный pgAdmin3. Из-за клиента глупо отказываться от такой замечательной базы. Тем более он есть. А если так посудить, то круче ibexperta ничего и нет, Так что теперь всё жизнь с furebird-ом возится, когда есть более продвинутые бд?

Comment: Я еще начинающий разработчик и активно использую клиент для разработки своих баз данных. Может быть в дальнейшем перейду на ту базу.

Comment: Не знаете где почитать про EAV модель на Русском. Не очень с энглиш:)

Comment: Предлагаю по-гуглить. Что-нибудь может и найдётся. Я не искал, да и не надо мне.

Comment: Что то мне кажется, что эта модель редко используется, из за недостатков.

Comment: Да не. Наоборот часто. Недостатки недостатками, но иначе никак. С появлением xml и потом json в бд, можно сделать и проще, хотя придётся пойти на некоторые компромиссы.

Comment: *Чтобы строки хранить как строки, числа как числа, даты как даты и т.д., тогда для каждого типа создаётся отдельная таблица.* А смысл - копейки считать? сериализовать всё в наиболее общий тип (string, json, xml - к чему душа лежит) - и можно обойтись одной таблицей значений атрибутов. А в таблице атрибутов хранить тип и выполнять соотв. преобразования при записи или выборке.

Comment: @LFDS Делайте  EAV, по нему по крайней мере можно сделать один индекс по значению, что позволит быстро искать. Если будут задачи массовых выборок до денормализуете БД, введете избыточность, помимо значений в EAV будете хранить собранный из них json в одном поле родительской таблицы и использовать его при получении всех свойств одного объекта, а EAV таблицу продолжите использовать при поиске

Comment: @Akina Не надо наводить тень на плетень. Про сохранение в строку упомянуто вскользь. Про подсчёт каких-то там копеек вообще слов не было.